# Difference warning level in Debug & Run Mode in Eclipse (using EPIC plugin) for Perl

Tags: eclipse, perl

How do I control the warning level in Eclipse for:

1. Debug Mode
2. Run Mode

I am getting many warnings when in **Run Mode** & no warning in **Debug Mode**